# understanding grep pattern in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, grep

What does it mean, in particular symbol * after end?

```
LOG=/root/$(basename $0).log
_notlogged(){
 if ! grep -q "# $*" $LOG; then
  echo "no"
 fi
 echo "yes"
}
_notlogged
```

Therefore, are grep regex rules special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quoted string `"# $*"` is subject to bash's parameter expansion before it get's passed to `grep`.

`$*` is a special variable in bash, it contains all positional parameters. Meaning the arguments to `_notlogged`.

If you call it like

```
_lotlogged foo
```

the expression passed to grep would be

```
grep -q "# foo"
```

Check the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) for further information.

Comment: `$0`, despite also having a number as its name, is not a positional parameter; it is a shell special parameter.

Comment: @chepner Following the bash manual you are right. I admit that I basically copied that statement from [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams). I've changed that. Thanks!